# javascript array 'undefined' console log

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined

I'd like to get 'roomname' out of the arrangement.. But when I run the log, I get undefined.

```
var roomNameArr = presenterArray.filter(function(item){
   console.log("## item.roomName : "+item.roomName);
   return item.roomName === viewerRoomName;
});
```

When I ran the log, the results below came out.

```
console.log("## roomNameArr : "+JSON.stringify(roomNameArr));

roomNameArr = [{"id":"1","pipeline":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":7,"id":"5465b70f-613f-4184-80d3-895b3dcfa2c7_kurento.MediaPipeline"},"webRtcEndpoint":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":6,"id":"5465b70f-613f-4184-80d3-895b3dcfa2c7_kurento.MediaPipeline/ac2bc699-bddf-44e2-a711-6444737109a1_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint"},"presenterRoomNum":"1","roomName":"1"}]
```

When I take a log to take out variable a, 'undefined' comes out.

```
console.log("## roomNameArr1 : "+roomNameArr['roomName']);
console.log("## roomNameArr1 : "+roomNameArr['5']);
```

I'm still wandering around and I need you to help me.

Comment: I'm assuming you are getting `undefined` on the last `console.log`. There is no `roomName` property in the `oomNameArr` array. Only on the objects inside it. `roomNameArr[0]['roomName']` should show `1`. Also, if you want a single result, you can use [**`Array.prototype.find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter`

Answer (score 1):

As `roomNameArr` is an array of objects, there is always an index number to all the objects within that array.

So if you want to access the `key:value` of any object within the `roomNameArr` array, you must have to define the index number on that object exists.

In your case, you have to write something like

```
console.log("## roomNameArr1 : "+roomNameArr[0]['roomName']);
```

or

```
console.log("## roomNameArr1 : "+roomNameArr[0].roomName);
```

to get the output correctly.